# C++ number of unique elements

Tags: c++, vector

Hi I have this function that gets the unique elements from a vector, but I was wondering how can make it get me the number of those unique elements as well.

```
void getUniqueSellers(vector<string> & result) {
        vector<CService>::iterator i= m_vData.begin();

        while(i != m_vData.end()) {

            if(find(result.begin(), result.end(), (*i).GetSeller()) == result.end()) {
                result.push_back((*i).GetSeller());
            }

            i++;
        }
    }

void main() 
{
    vector<string> res;
    myAnalyzer.getUniqueSellers(res);
    vector<string>::iterator i=res.begin();
    while(i!=res.end()) {
        cout<< *i<<",";
        i++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

Comment: `void main` is not a legal signature.

Comment: you mean how many occurrence of each of those unique number or total number of unique numbers?

Comment: std::sort and std::unique or insert into std::set which only inserts unique elements. From there you can get the size or all the unique elements

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have a list of them, it's easy to find the size:

```
res.size()
```

However, I suggest you drop the recreated algorithm to do it and use an existing one. I also suggest you return a value instead of using an out parameter:

```
std::vector<std::string> getUniqueSellers() {
    std::sort(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end());
    m_vData.erase(std::unique(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end()), m_vData.end());

    std::vector<std::string> res;
    std::transform(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end(), std::back_inserter(res), [](const CService &cs) {return cs.GetSeller();});

    return res;
}
```

I used a C++11 lambda, so you can replace that with a normal functor if you don't have C++11. This also requires you to implement equality for `CService` based on `GetSeller()`. Alternatively, if you don't want to modify `m_vData`, you can make a copy or use `std::set`:

```
std::set<std::string> res;
std::transform(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end(), std::back_inserter(res), [](const CService &cs) {return cs.GetSeller();});
return std::vector(res.begin(), res.end());
```

Comment: I've founded a more simple way to my question. I've added this line cout<<"Number of unique Sellers: "<<result.size()<<endl; add the end of my void function but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @user2374907, Ah, I see. I assumed you meant the number of times each occurred. I'll update my answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a vector of string, you can make a class of `seller` that contains a `string name` and an `int count`. and return a vector of that.

If you find a duplicate, instead of ignoring it, you can just incriment the `count`